# How Can I Save Converted file to the same source directory in Amazon S3 and Media Convert Using this python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this **convert.py** code from amazon samples to save converted videos on S3 bucket. I am not familiar with Python codes. How can I change the code so that it will save to the same directory and not on `'assets/' + assetID + '/MP4/' + sourceS3Basename`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import json
import os
import uuid
import boto3
import datetime
import random

from botocore.client import ClientError

def handler(event, context):

    assetID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    sourceS3Bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    sourceS3Key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    sourceS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket + '/' + sourceS3Key
    sourceS3Basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sourceS3))[0]
    destinationS3 = 's3://' + os.environ['DestinationBucket']
    destinationS3basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(destinationS3))[0]
    mediaConvertRole = os.environ['MediaConvertRole']
    region = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
    statusCode = 200
    body = {}

    # Use MediaConvert SDK UserMetadata to tag jobs with the assetID 
    # Events from MediaConvert will have the assetID in UserMedata
    jobMetadata = {'assetID': assetID}

    print (json.dumps(event))

    try:
        # Job settings are in the lambda zip file in the current working directory
        with open('job.json') as json_data:
            jobSettings = json.load(json_data)
            print(jobSettings)

        # get the account-specific mediaconvert endpoint for this region
        mc_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region)
        endpoints = mc_client.describe_endpoints()

        # add the account-specific endpoint to the client session 
        client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region, endpoint_url=endpoints['Endpoints'][0]['Url'], verify=False)

        # Update the job settings with the source video from the S3 event and destination 
        # paths for converted videos
        jobSettings['Inputs'][0]['FileInput'] = sourceS3

        S3KeyHLS = 'assets/' + assetID + '/HLS/' + sourceS3Basename
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['HlsGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyHLS

        S3KeyWatermark = 'assets/' + assetID + '/MP4/' + sourceS3Basename
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][1]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyWatermark

        S3KeyThumbnails = 'assets/' + assetID + '/Thumbnails/' + sourceS3Basename
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][2]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyThumbnails     

        print('jobSettings:')
        print(json.dumps(jobSettings))

        # Convert the video using AWS Elemental MediaConvert
        job = client.create_job(Role=mediaConvertRole, UserMetadata=jobMetadata, Settings=jobSettings)
        print (json.dumps(job, default=str))

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Exception: %s' % e)
        statusCode = 500
        raise

    finally:
        return {
            'statusCode': statusCode,
            'body': json.dumps(body),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same S3 source bucket in place of your S3 destination bucket.
You can use **regular expression (regex)** to extract out the base path for the S3 Object from its key.

Below is your code with enhancements to complete your requirement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import json
import os
import uuid
import boto3
import datetime
import random
import re

from botocore.client import ClientError

def handler(event, context):

    assetID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    sourceS3Bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    sourceS3Key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    sourceS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket + '/' + sourceS3Key
    sourceS3Basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sourceS3))[0]
    destinationS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket
    sourceS3KeyPath = re.findall('^(.*)/', str(sourceS3Key))
    if len(sourceS3KeyPath) == 1:
        destinationS3 = destinationS3 + '/' + str(sourceS3KeyPath[0])
    destinationS3basename = sourceS3Basename
    mediaConvertRole = os.environ['MediaConvertRole']
    region = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION']
    statusCode = 200
    body = {}

    # Use MediaConvert SDK UserMetadata to tag jobs with the assetID 
    # Events from MediaConvert will have the assetID in UserMedata
    jobMetadata = {'assetID': assetID}

    print (json.dumps(event))

    try:
        # Job settings are in the lambda zip file in the current working directory
        with open('job.json') as json_data:
            jobSettings = json.load(json_data)
            print(jobSettings)

        # get the account-specific mediaconvert endpoint for this region
        mc_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region)
        endpoints = mc_client.describe_endpoints()

        # add the account-specific endpoint to the client session 
        client = boto3.client('mediaconvert', region_name=region, endpoint_url=endpoints['Endpoints'][0]['Url'], verify=False)

        # Update the job settings with the source video from the S3 event and destination 
        # paths for converted videos
        jobSettings['Inputs'][0]['FileInput'] = sourceS3

        S3KeyHLS = 'hls'
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['HlsGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyHLS

        S3KeyWatermark = 'watermark'
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][1]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyWatermark

        S3KeyThumbnails = 'thumbnails'
        jobSettings['OutputGroups'][2]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \
            = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyThumbnails     

        print('jobSettings:')
        print(json.dumps(jobSettings))

        # Convert the video using AWS Elemental MediaConvert
        job = client.create_job(Role=mediaConvertRole, UserMetadata=jobMetadata, Settings=jobSettings)
        print (json.dumps(job, default=str))

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Exception: %s' % e)
        statusCode = 500
        raise

    finally:
        return {
            'statusCode': statusCode,
            'body': json.dumps(body),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        }
```

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "name 'event2' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/convert.py\", line 22, in handler\n    sourceS3KeyPath = re.findall('^(.*)/', str(event2['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']))\n"
  ]
}

Comment: looks like this works, now i just need to save the HLS files with the same filename and adding _360 _720 etc to it. can you help me with that? thanks

Comment: You need to update this line `S3KeyHLS = 'hls'`, replace `'hls'` with what you need to add to the filename.

Comment: how can I get the filename of the original video without the .mp4 on it? That is what I need. thanks you.

Comment: original_file_name = sourceS3Key.replace(sourceS3KeyPath, "")

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

To provide some context on the code here -- source and destination buckets for your data are defined at the top of the script in this block. (`#` at line start is the comment operator for Python, I've added them in to help provide a better understanding of the code).

```
# The S3 bucket for the source is pulled in from an event
# (I assume it's when a new object is added to an S3 bucket, which would trigger this script)
sourceS3Bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
sourceS3Key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
sourceS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket + '/' + sourceS3Key
sourceS3Basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sourceS3))[0]

# The S3 bucket for the destination is pulled in through an environment variable using the os.environ() method
destinationS3 = 's3://' + os.environ['DestinationBucket']
destinationS3basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(destinationS3))[0]
```

There are a few ways to make changes to achieve what you're looking for. The example code is written in such a way where it can accept input for any S3 bucket and parse the event to find the file in question, whereas the destination bucket seems to be read in from an environment variable defined elsewhere (a config file, likely).

It looks like there are 3 objects created from each one of these jobs (HLS, watermark, and thumbnail), so you may want to make sure there are no filename collisions that could potentially cause overwriting (both between source and processed file, as well as between the three different outputs). The original code works in such a way where each processing job creates its own folder, with subfolders each containing one of the 3 outputs from the conversion job.

I'd advise against dumping all of the files directly in an S3 bucket in in an unordered fashion, but if you're set on it, this block of code would change from this:

```
S3KeyHLS = 'assets/' + assetID + '/HLS/' + sourceS3Basename 
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['HlsGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyHLS

S3KeyWatermark = 'assets/' + assetID + '/MP4/' + sourceS3Basename
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][1]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyWatermark

S3KeyThumbnails = 'assets/' + assetID + '/Thumbnails/' + sourceS3Basename
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][2]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = destinationS3 + '/' + S3KeyThumbnails
```

to this (I've added an appended string at the end of each of the three outputs):

```
S3KeyHLS = sourceS3 + assetID + 'key'
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][0]['OutputGroupSettings']['HlsGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = S3KeyHLS

S3KeyWatermark = sourceS3 + assetID + 'watermark'
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][1]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = S3KeyWatermark

S3KeyThumbnails = sourceS3 + assetID + 'thumbnail'
jobSettings['OutputGroups'][2]['OutputGroupSettings']['FileGroupSettings']['Destination'] \ = S3KeyThumbnails
```

Again, I wouldn't necessarily advise this (potential names[ace collisions as your output is filename-dependent, unstructured output will be very difficult to parse) If you can talk a little bit more to your use case, I'd be happy to help with more suggestions.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will give it a go and let you know if it works.

Comment: I would like to save the converted files as filename-low, filename-medium-, filename-high on the same directory where the uploaded file was.

Comment: One more thing to note: I would be wary of this method because you may accidentally cause an infinite loop if your lambda trigger is an object upload into the root directory of S3, as this will create an infinite loop where each lambda will create 3 more objects, each of which will trigger their own lambda ad infinitum.

Comment: nmwalsh, I added an s3 trigger for .mp4 files only and I think converted video is not .mp4 right?

Comment: I can’t tell from the context supplied, but if it works as you described, then it should be fine, as none of the outputs are .mp4